# Ubuntu 22.04 bluetooth and wifi don't work

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 22.04

Another one of these, but my problem seems to be slightly different from the ones I found.

This has no return:

```
$ sudo dmesg -T | grep -i Bluetooth
```

This also has no return:

```
$ hciconfig -a
```

But, then, after running hciconfig, dmesg returns:

```
sudo dmesg -T | grep Bluetooth
[qui set 29 01:14:46 2022] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[qui set 29 01:14:46 2022] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[qui set 29 01:14:46 2022] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[qui set 29 01:14:46 2022] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[qui set 29 01:14:46 2022] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

I can't find my my bluetooth device in both lspci and lsusb:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake-U v1 4c Host Bridge/DRAM Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPC Premium Controller/eSPI Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. U-SNS8154P3 NVMe SSD (rev 01)


$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0461:4e90 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Wireless Keyboard Mouse Kit
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have no idea what to do. This whole thing happened because my bluetooth and wi-fi stopped working all of the sudden in Ubuntu 20.04, so I changed to 22.04.

If I turn off the laptop using the power button (holding for 5 seconds), when I turn on, the bluetooth icon appears, but it can't load any device. After waiting for some time, if I turn it off, it breaks completely again: the icon disappears and the message displayed in the settings is: *Bluetooth Turned Off. Turn on to connect devices and receive file transfers.*

If I run dmesg immediately after this (without restarting), I get:

```
$ sudo dmesg -T | grep -i Bluetooth
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 0 week 30 2018
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-1.sfi
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[qui set 29 01:18:38 2022] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[qui set 29 01:18:39 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[qui set 29 01:18:39 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1680409 usecs
[qui set 29 01:18:39 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[qui set 29 01:18:39 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 14791 usecs
[qui set 29 01:18:39 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-19-0-1.ddc
[qui set 29 01:18:39 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[qui set 29 01:18:39 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 126 week 5 2022
[qui set 29 01:18:43 2022] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[qui set 29 01:18:43 2022] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[qui set 29 01:18:43 2022] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[qui set 29 01:19:12 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to restart LE scan: status 31
[qui set 29 01:19:26 2022] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read MSFT supported features (-110)
```

**EDIT 1**
Ok, the behaviour just keep getting weirder. Using the powerrbutton seemed to "reset" the bluetooth and wifi, which would then break in mid session, but at least they work for a bit. Sometimes, the wifi will break mid-session and the bluetooth will stay on, other times both will fail...

Answering **David's** comment, I don't usually use the powerbutton. I started using it as a test because, in another thread, a user gave me the intuition that the laptop might not have been turning off completely.

Also, the bluetooth and wifi are part of the same chip, the Intel® Wireless-AC 9560, which is a built-in

Answering **Archisman Panigrahi**, I did a fresh install.

**Edit2**
More info. I completely erased the disk and installed windows (and only windows). The bluetooth didn't work in the beginning but the wifi did. After a restart, both the bluetooth and wifi were working consistently with no problem for some hours (with a lot of restarts in the middle).

Then, I decided to install ubuntu. And, while I was in the try mode installing it, both the wifi and bluetooth broke. Then, I stopped the installation, and came back to windows to see if they still worked there. They didn't work anymore.

Whatever the problem is, it's persisting in between restarts, which explains why using the powerbutton helps initially. I have very little knowledge of what does persist after a restart.

**Edit3**
Used a bootable manjaro and the same that happens in linux happened here. Bluetooth and Wifi start well and after some minutes, they disappear. The results of the **dmseg** were also the same.

Comment: Upgrading to a new version NEVER fixes a problem. You would have been better to have found the issue and fixed the problem before the upgrade. How often do you use the power button to shut down the machine? Every time you do that you risk corrupting the OS. Is the Bluetooth device built in or a dongle? Please edit the question and add this info.

Comment: Did you perform a fresh install or an upgrade?

Comment: Try temporarily disabling tlp, if you're using it.

Comment: It looks to me like a hardware error. TBH I won't loss any more time with this, as you can buy a €17 USB Wifi and Bluetooth device. Cheers

Comment: what model of wifi card and bluetooth fo you have? From what I see the PC must be fairly new judging from the processor. I would suggest whether you could install the drivers manually for both devices. Sometimes for newer models there are no drivers available out of the box

Comment: don't you need 100+ reputation to place a bounty for 100 ?

Comment: Did you find this? https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html